# Why are primitive types such as Int erased to Object in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-erasure, autoboxing

In Scala,

```
{ x: Option[Int] => x }
   .getClass
   .getMethod("apply", classOf[Option[_]])
   .getGenericParameterTypes
```

returns `Array(scala.Option<java.lang.Object>)`. I'd initially been expecting to see instead `Array(scala.Option<scala.Int>)`, but I see that [`scala.Int`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html) is a value class (extends `AnyVal`) 'whose instances are not represented as objects by the underlying host system'.

I still don't understand the erasure to `Object`, though. Couldn't it be the much more useful `java.lang.Integer`?

Comment: That isn't Scala doing that -- it's Java. To get useful, as in non-Object, results from "GenericParameterTypes" (a method of a Java Class object), a Subclass has to be created. Scala *didn't* create a Subclass, say `OptionInt`, for `Option[Int]`. (See @specialized, perhaps?)

Comment: @pst; I think you're on the wrong track. Change `Int` to `Symbol` above and you get `Array(scala.Option<scala.Symbol>)`.

Comment: Hmm, well there goes my hypothesis :-/ I blame compiler magic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Couldn't it be the much more useful `java.lang.Integer`?

Yes, and that was even the case, once. Unfortunately, that leads to broken type signatures. That is, *it is impossible to generate correct bytecode in all situations if `Int` is erased to `java.lang.Integer`*.

There isn't a single ticket or commit about this, but the one that changed this particular behavior is [scala/bug#4214](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/4214), in [this commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/e42733e9fe1f3af591976fbb48b66035253d85b9).

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at `git log --grep=Integer` but didn't see anything obvious.

Comment: @ScottMorrison You should have searched for "signature". Anyway, I found it for you. See revised answer.