# Difference in type erasure of List[Int] and List[Integer]

Tags: java, scala, type-erasure, scala-java-interop

Why does `List[scala.Int]` type erase to `List[Object]` whilst `Integer` in `List[java.lang.Integer]` seems
to be preserved? For example, `javap` for

```
object Foo {
  def fooInt: List[scala.Int] = ???
  def fooInteger: List[java.lang.Integer] = ???
}
```

outputs

```
public scala.collection.immutable.List<java.lang.Object> fooInt();
public scala.collection.immutable.List<java.lang.Integer> fooInteger();
```

where we see `Integer` was preserved in second case. The docs [state](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or `Object` if the type parameters are unbounded.

Is this perhaps due to the "bounds" clause? If so, where is this bound specified?

Comment: I think that it has something to do with this https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html.html

Comment: can you post the _entire_ `javap` output here? `-c -v -p` please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are primitive types such as Int erased to Object in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167430/why-are-primitive-types-such-as-int-erased-to-object-in-scala)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am *not* a scala developer, take this with a grain of salt. The erasure *is* the same:

```
public static scala.collection.immutable.List<java.lang.Object> fooInt();
descriptor: ()Lscala/collection/immutable/List;

public static scala.collection.immutable.List<java.lang.Integer> fooInt();
descriptor: ()Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
```

look at the `descriptor` parameter; that is what gets referenced at *call sites* at the byte code level.

When you simply do `javap`, it "cheats" a little bit by looking at the `Signature` parameter (read further) so that it shows you this little inoffensive lie.

Now think about it. Let's take this method and place it in class `A`:

```
static List<Integer> test() {
    return null; // or whatever that is not the point
}
```

we compile it, share the `.class` file to someone else. That someone else uses it in this form: (without actually having source code for `A`).

```
public void testMe() {
    Integer x = A.test().get(0);
}
```

if you look at the byte-code, you will see:

```
    5: invokeinterface #3,  2 // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
    10: checkcast     #4      // class java/lang/Integer
```

There is an immediate question that has to arise: how does it know about `Integer`  (via that `checkcast`) if generics are erased? The answer is the optional `Signature` that is generated when `A` is compiled, or in your cases:

```
 ()Lscala/collection/immutable/List<Ljava/lang/Object;>; //fooInt
 ()Lscala/collection/immutable/List<Ljava/lang/Integer;>; // fooInteger
```

This `Signature` information is what is used by the compiler to enforce type safety at *callsites*, via runtime checks; if this field would not be present - that would have been impossible.

Now to *why* the `Signature` of `scalac` generates `Object` (thus zero type safety for callers) is something that the duplicate addresses. I've tried to read the issue and it's not an easy read- I'll just go with "I trust you".

---

A little more explanations: `Signature` appeared in `java-5` when generics where added. Until then, all call-sites where referenced by `descriptor`, changing that to `Signature` instead would mean that existing code would break; thus never done. Thus `Signature` became optional and used in a different way - for `checkcast`. At least this is what I am strongly inclined to assume :)